# Why is my data not displaying in the table in react

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know why my data isn't displaying, it console.logs 'x[0]', 'x[1]', 'x[2]', and 'x[3]' fine in my return statement. I'm pretty new to react and programming in general so I have no idea why this doesn't work.

I would just expect it to fill the rows of the table like the 2 I've manually coded in.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./stylesheets/oddsmatcher-table.css"


const App = () => {
    const [wow, setWow] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(DATA)    
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const newData = data.data.slice(0, 10)
                
                const k = newData.map(x => {
                    return [x.date, x.event_name, x.bookmaker_name, x.exchange]
                })
    
                setWow(k)
                console.log(k)
            })
    }, [])
    
    
    return(
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Event</th>
                    <th>Bookie</th>
                    <th>Exchange</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>25-09-2020</td>
                    <td>Man United vs Liverpool</td>
                    <td>Bet365</td>
                    <td>Smarkets</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>26-09-2020</td>
                    <td>Arsenal vs Man City</td>
                    <td>Coral</td>
                    <td>Betfair Exchange</td>
                </tr>
                {wow.forEach(x => {
                    return(
                        <tr>
                            <td>{x[0]}</td>
                            <td>{x[1]}</td>
                            <td>{x[2]}</td>
                            <td>{x[3]}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Try switching your `wow.forEach` to this:

```jsx
{wow.map((x, index) => {
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      {x.map((dataPiece) => (
        <td key={dataPiece}>{dataPiece}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
})}
```

Here's the Codesandbox I was using to test. I replaced your async fetch with a global variable with what I think your `wow` data looks like:
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-glitter-mf0tg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Let me know if that works. If it doesn't, can you post an example of what your fetched data looks like?